# If $A$ is an uncountable set and $B \subset A$, $B \neq A$, how can i prove that $B$ is also uncountable?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

If $A$ is an uncountable set and $B \subset A$, $B \neq A$, how can i prove that $B$ is also uncountable?
I considered to take $a \in A$ and $B = A \setminus \{a\}$. But I don’t get anywhere, any help?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Take $B = \emptyset$ and $A = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Suppose the opposite, i.e. that $B$ is countable. (This will work if and only if you removed a countable number of elements from $A$, like you did in your example.)

Comment: Of course you're not getting anywhere since it's simply not true.

Comment: However, if $B$ is uncountable, then so must $A$.

Answer (score 2):

That is not true.
You have that $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.